# Get Row ID for Updating without Redirection

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have made a PHP/MySQL table that has an edit button with a link in each row.

The Edit button is linked to the same page but with the id of the row item, the purpose of which is for the edit PHP getting the ID of the selected item.

```php
<table width="70%">
    <tr class="tablehead">
        <th>ITEM ID</th>
        <th>ITEM DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>OPTIONS</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    $username = $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $username";

    $result = $conn2->query($sql);

    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $id=$row["id"];
        $itemid=$row["item_id"];
        $item=$row["item_description"];
        $qty=$row["item_quantity"];
        $price=$row["item_price"];

        if ($qty > 0) {
            $status = "Available";
        }

        else {
            $status = "Out of Stock";
        }

        echo "<tr id='" . "$id'>" ;
        echo "<td><span class='tabtext'>" . $itemid . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class='tabtext'>" . $item . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class='tabtext'>" . $qty . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class='tabtext'>" . $price . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class='tabtext'>" . $status . "</span></td>";
        echo '<td><a href="inventory.php?id=' . $id . '"><span class="tabedit"></span></a><a href="inventory.php?id=' . $id . '"><span class="tabdel"></span></a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

The edit button on click also shows a hidden div using jQuery where the edit panel is displayed.

```
<div id="editprodbg">
    <div id="innerprodcont">
        <div id="innerprod">
            <a href="#"><span class="editprodclose"></span></a>
            <h2 class="textheader">Add Product</h2>
            <form action="editprod.php" id="editprod" method="post">
                <div class="inputbox"><input name="item_id" type="text" class="prodbox" placeholder="Item ID"></input></div>
                <div class="inputbox"><input name="item" type="text" class="prodbox" placeholder="Product Name"></input></div>
                <div class="inputbox"><input name="quant" type="text" class="prodbox" placeholder="Quantity"></input></div>
                <div class="inputbox"><input name="price" type="text" class="prodbox" placeholder="Price"></input></div>
            </form>
            <button class="editbut2" form="editprod" ><span>Edit Product</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am having a problem where as I click the edit button the CSS returns to the original state because of the redirection which in turn hides the Edit Panel.

Is there any other approach to this where as I click the edit button, the ID of the row is stored and the CSS is not reverted back to the original state?

By the way, I am not looking into the option of redirecting to another page for editing the row, only through a form in the same page as a button is clicked and shows the div container.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. You should add come code and examples. As of right now, I think you are trying to make web based Excel.

Comment: I added the codes of the table and also the div of the hidden one. Basically my problem is that when I click on the edit button for editing my rows, '<div id="editprod">' shows but after a few seconds the browser is redirected to 'inventory.php?id=" . $id . "' which returns the css to the original state hiding again the edit panel making me unable input my changes to the form. 

Is there anyway around this? I mean storing the id of the row without the Edit div being hidden? Because the link is the only way I know how to store the id of the current row.

Comment: Still a little unclear but, If i get it then try these.  instead of <a href="inventory.php?id=' . $id . '"> use <a href="#' . $id . '"> or try JQuery http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to understanding my problem! May I ask, what's the difference of using the two a href that you've given?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm starting to understand what you meant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just as bassxzero has commented.

Instead of `<a href="inventory.php?id=' . $id . '">`

I used `<a href="#?id=' . $id . '">` to prevent any redirection, at the same time store the id of the row in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

for the same case i prefer use jquery  to process inventory.php?id=$id, something like

`$('#link_to_inventory_php').click(function) {
     $('#div_to_proccess_inventory_php').load('inventory.php?id='+id); 
}`

so you dont need to load inventory.php whole of page just in some div of your page

Comment: How do you use this to get specifically each rows id?

Comment: I use hidden field to identify the rows id, or you can use any other selector like div id or div class, anything you want
  <input type='hidden' value={$id} id='rowid'>  
  and :
 $('#link_to_inventory_php').click(function) {
   id= $( "#rowid" ).val();
   $('#div_to_proccess_inventory_php').load('inventory.php?id='+id); 
 }